# FeathersJS mount service at root

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I am building a microservices architecture using FeathersJS and I only need one service per application, so I will mount that service to the root (`/`) of each app.
I have tried to do that using `/` as a path when I'm generating the service (Mongoose) and deleting the `app.use('/', express.static(app.get('public')));` line from `app.js` and it works as it should when I'm accessing the base path (it lists all entries), but when I try `/421jsadi23o1sj` to find an entry, it returns 404.

I think it gets that ID as being a service's path and looks for it.

This is my *businesses.service.js* file:

```
const createService = require('feathers-mongoose');
const createModel = require('../../models/businesses.model');
const hooks = require('./businesses.hooks');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');

  const options = {
    name: 'businesses',
    Model,
    paginate
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/', createService(options));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks and filters
  const service = app.service('/');

  service.hooks(hooks);

  app.publish(() => {
    // Here you can add event publishers to channels set up in `channels.js`
    // To publish only for a specific event use `app.publish(eventname, () => {})`

    // e.g. to publish all service events to all authenticated users use
    // return app.channel('authenticated');
  });
};
```

Had anyone came across this issue? Any ideas about how it can be solved?

Comment: Ref https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/718